# Delete part of a string after a match, but not the line using sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file a.com as

```
N-N3-0.0012   -1  5  6  7  L
C-CT-0.002225 -1  5  8  9  H H-3-1
H-H-0.003534  -1  6  3  4  L
```

I want a.com to modify as

```
N  -1  5  6  7  L
C  -1  5  8  9  H H-3-1
H  -1  6  3  4  L
```

Basically, I want to delete everything after the first "-" match in the first column, but retain all other columns.

I can do this by extracting first column into a file and then using sed to delete everything after the match "-" and replace that with first column in the original file. But I was wondering is there a  easy command with sed,  for not to delete rest of the line, but rest of the column after a match.

Comment: Are there really blank lines between every line of data?

Comment: No there is no black line. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```
kent$  awk '{sub(/-.*/,"",$1)}7' a.com
N -1 5 6 7 L
C -1 5 8 9 H H-3-1
H -1 6 3 4 L
```

sed:

```
kent$  sed 's/-\S*//' file
N   -1  5  6  7  L
C -1  5  8  9  H H-3-1
H  -1  6  3  4  L
```

if you want to keep the format:

```
kent$  sed 's/-\S*\s*/ /' file
N -1  5  6  7  L
C -1  5  8  9  H H-3-1
H -1  6  3  4  L
```

Comment: I have similar problem except my delimiter is a "." but somehow I think it needs an escape sequence, how can I handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Since others have provided the solution with sed and awk, here is the script with pure shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r a b
do
   echo "${a%%-*}" "$b"
done < file
```